# StageWebView fails to show keyboard on iPad/ios6.1

Tags: air, adobe, air-native-extension, stagewebview

We are using StageWebView on iPad to show special sharing pages to user. Everything works fine (page loaded ok) except that after we upgraded our test iPad to 6.1, stagewebview stopped to popup keyboard when user taps on input fields. There is cursor but no keyboard. assignFocus does not help too. So it is not usable for pages that requires keyboard interaction. For now we are thinking to replace stagewebview with UIWebView ANE from darkredz.com

Is there any workarounds?

Answer (score 1):

I just found a reason! i took me 3 days to debug to the root. To find the reason i implemented modal view with browser in it, but even in this modally shown browser (inside UINavigationCotroller) keyboards was missed too!

And all this madness because of single ANE, specifically pl.mateuszmackowiak.nativeANE
http://mateuszmackowiak.wordpress.com/2012/01/18/as3-native-alert-android-ios-window/
I used progress.NativeProgress component from it. After using this component rootViewController of whole application became invalid!

What i found in short:

```
UIWindow* keyWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]keyWindow];
* keyWindowController = [keyWindow rootViewController];

1) keyWindowController != nil before using NativeProgress
2) keyWindowController == nil after using NativeProgress
```

This is really evil behaviour, because without root view controller keyboard can not be show in normal way. Shame on ANE developer :(